# add-in commands no longer open taskpane automatically

Tags: office-js

Before using officeJS add-in commands when I installed an add-in to a workbook, the taskpane would open automatically when opening it later, or opening another workbook during the same session. Now with the commands enabled, the user must go to the ribbon and open the taskpane manually.

Is there a way to have the taskpane open automatically as add-ins used to behave before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(update) Link to the feature that enables this: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document.md

--
Previous response

Not currently. We are working on a feature that will help you achieve a similar behavior without the side effects that "inserting a taskpane" caused (e.g. it was actually pretty strange for many users to cause a pane to auto-open with a document). Our thinking for the feature we are working is to allow developers to explicitly designate a pane to be opened (on the manifest) as well as which documents should trigger that (via a special setting you can set with office.context.document.settings). Don't have a specific timing on when the feature will land.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer here: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document?product=excel

...You can use add-in commands in your Office Add-in to extend the Office UI by adding buttons to the Office ribbon. When users click your command button, an action occurs, such as opening a task pane.

This works only for workbooks users open. Store acquired add-ins won't be able to auto-open their task-panes.